# Getting Selected Values from Radiobuttonlist and Checkboxlist in ListView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm creating a quiz application in ASP.NET, I've displayed the Question and Answer using ListView and used a DataPager for Next Previous button. I would like to know the code on how to retain answers per question.

Answer (score 0):

This is static datatable binding. you can bind it with your database value.
aspx page like

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstQuestions" OnItemDataBound="lstQuestions_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestionNo" Text='<%# "Q. "+ Eval("No") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                Select Answer:
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoAnswers" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
</form>
```

aspx.cs page like:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //this portion is dynamic
        //You can get questions from your database.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Question");
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i, "Your Question -" + i);
        lstQuestions.DataSource = dt;
        lstQuestions.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void lstQuestions_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    //this portion is dynamic
  //You can get answers from your database.
    RadioButtonList rdo = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rdoAnswers");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Answers");
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        dt.Rows.Add(i, "Your Answer -" + i);
    rdo.DataSource = dt;
    rdo.DataMember = "Answers";
    rdo.DataValueField = "No";
    rdo.DataBind();
}
```